# What about security questions with custom forms?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have reasons to believe that the security will be more complex if we build custom forms. Custom forms are opened by ribbon buttons, what about the security? How can we narrow down the acces to such custom forms to authorized personel, groups, users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security for me is usually just an:

```
if(!web.SiteGroups["group name"].ContainsCurrentUser) response.redirect("MyNotAuthorized.aspx");
```

That just gets thrown in page_load or something along those lines.